# Запуск Cron по времени

Tags: cron, crontab

Объясните пожалуйста такой момент.
Мне надо запускать скрипт кроном каждые 10 минут, но в круглые десятки (т.е. в 00 минут, в 10, в 20 и т.д).

Соответственно вариант в таком случае подходит только

0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /bin/sh mysqript.sh

А следующий вариант, не факт что запустится в 00?

*/10 * * * * /bin/sh mysqript.sh

Comment: запустится. `*/10` следует читать не _каждые десять минут_, а _каждую десятую минуту_, т.е. 00 входит туда

Comment: Вот тут можете проверить: [`*/10 * * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_*_*_*_*). Там на сайте можно увидеть, что ближайший запуск будет ровно в десятую минуту.